# Set input tag value in Underscore template

Tags: javascript, templates, input, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am trying to set the input tag value from the javascript object passed to it.

Assume item has these values item = ['item one', 'item two']

```
<input type="text" 
        name="choice" 
        val=<%= item[0] %>
        data_id=<%= item[1] %>/>
```

I expect the output like this

```
<input type="text" 
        name="choice" 
        val="item one"
        data_id="item two"/>
```

But the actual generated html is :

```
   <input type="text" 
        name="choice" 
        val="item"
        "one"
        data_id="item" />
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What does the JavaScript look like? Why aren't you quoting your attributes in the template?

Comment: It worked like a charm. after quoting the attributes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short)

comments, I quoted the attributes in the template and it worked fine.

```
<input type="text" 
        name="choice" 
        val="<%= item[0] %>"
        data_id="<%= item[1] %>"/>
```